# Could not connect to domain:3306 : Read timed out java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: mysql, centos7, mariadb

I'm using centos 7 and MariaDB 11.
I was connected to my database and it worked fine. but now I got this error message:

```
Could not connect to domain.com:3306: Read timed out java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

My IP is not blocked and my port(3306) is open. I don't know the problem what is!
I checked my connection with another IP, but I got the same error.
max_connection is 200.

Comment: Did you check the database logs?

Comment: Do you check the firewall ? Do you activate IPv6 after IPv4 ? how the name is resolved ?

Comment: @Dom Which firewall section should I check?

Comment: You must check all the firewall between the client and the server. So Client Output firewall, optional intermediate firewall and server firewall. Check the logs, look at the rules : is there something blocking the connection ?